# How to find <li> in between 2 numbers in JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have an issue with JQuery i couldn't solved.

For Example:

```
<ul class="booking-list">
   <li data-price="250"> ... </li>
   <li data-price="350"> ... </li>
</ul>
```

`#price-slider` is:
`<input type="hidden" id="price-slider" value="100;300">`

Should return both `<li>` tags. (Both are Between 100 and 300).

In Jquery:

```
$("#irs-1").on("click", function () {
    var priceSlider = $('#price-slider').val().split(';');
    var min_price = priceSlider[0];
    var max_price = priceSlider[1];

    var $booking = $('ul.booking-list'),
        $bookingli = $booking.children('li');

    var $matchingLi = $bookingli.filter(function() {
        var price = parseFloat($(this).data('data-price'));
        return price >= min_price && price <= max_price;
    });

    $matchingLi.detach().appendTo($booking);
});
```

But i returns nothing :(

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, @RickHitchcock , update question :-)

Comment: Hi, @JonathanLonowski , Please check again question.

Comment: Since when is `350` between `100` and `300`? O.o

Comment: `.data('data-price')` should be `.data('price')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
parseFloat($(this).data('data-price'));
```

to:

```
parseFloat($(this).data('price'));
```

The "data-" isn't needed and will actually look for a property named "data-data-price."

Also note that `detach()` isn't needed if you're simply moving an object.  `appendTo()` automatically does the move.

Wouldn't be a bad idea to apply `parseFloat()` to the `priceSlider` array elements, so you're comparing numbers to numbers.  But it doesn't actually matter in this context, because JavaScript will convert the `min_price` and `max_price` strings to numbers before doing the comparison.

Comment: `parseFloat()` also isn't really necessary with `.data()`. [The method already applies parsing to numeric values.](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5)

Comment: @JonathanLonowski, that's interesting, I did not know that.

Comment: Thank you for help me, after change to `.data('price')` not work this code!

Comment: I change to `var price = $(this).data('price');`.

Comment: @mySun, you seem to be appending the matched `<li>` elements onto their own parent (`$booking`).  So nothing actually happens.  Do you mean to move them somewhere else?

Comment: Thank you for help me, The problem I found
 :-)